# how to send facebook Notification or message via its api?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-rest-api

please let me know how can i Send facebook Notification or message via its API through a facebook app?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Old REST API to send notifications to users who have authenticated your application. First you must request the "email" [extended permission](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions) from the user, then you can use the [notifications.sendEmail](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/notifications.sendEmail) method to send them the notification.

Answer (score 1):

I used this dialog to send message one my one. But had no luck to send message to facebook account successfully.

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/send?app_id=MY_APP_ID&name=Check This Website&to=MY_APPLICATIONS_USER_ID&link=MY_WEBSITE_LINK&redirect_uri=MY_APPLICATION_URL
```